# change navbar text color on scroll in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

hello i am new to react i want to change my text color of nav  into white on scroll for this i did  following

```
useEffect(() => {
    const header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    const navText = document.getElementById("onScroll");
    const sticky = header.offsetTop;
    const stickyNav = navText.offsetTop;

const scrollCallBack = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky ) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    navText.className("navText");
    
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    navText.classList.remove("navText");
    
  }
});
```

and this is my nav code

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
              <Link to="/" id="onScroll" className={`nav-item nav-link ${className}`}>
                Home
              </Link>
              <Link to="/service" id="onScroll"  className={`nav-item  nav-link ${className}`}>
                Services
              </Link>
              <a href="#" id="onScroll" className={`nav-item nav-link ${className}`}>
                About
              </a>
              <Link to="/works" id="onScroll" className={`nav-item nav-link ${className}`}>
                How it works
              </Link>
              <Link href="#" to="/covid" id="onScroll" className={`nav-item nav-link ${className}`}>
                COVID
              </Link>
            </div>
```

but on UI only one text (home) changes it color i want all text to change color with out using jquery
[image]

here is my css

```
.nav-color {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  color: #12356a !important;
}
.sticky {
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2  !important;
  background: #12356a;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the CSS?

Comment: sure i have edited my question

Comment: if every p element has the same class you can just document.querySelectorAll(".your_class"), and then iterate through them with a .forEach(), or you can make a css variable for their color in the parent element and then just document.getElementById("the_parent_id").setProperty("--your-css-variable-name",  "white or whatever"). Hope it helps.

Comment: can you show it in a code

Comment: parent is nav and text is in the  link tag

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it by this method hope it will help some one else

```
const [isSticky, setSticky] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollCallBack = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 0 ) {
        setSticky(true)        
      } else {
        setSticky(false)       
      }
    });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollCallBack);
    };
  }, []);
<Link to="/"  className={`nav-item nav-link ${isSticky? "navText": null} `}>
```